# Symfony : Customer query for load user

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

With Symfony 3.3 and Twig, when I call " app.user ", this query is loaded :

```
SELECT
    t0.id AS id_1,
    t0.username AS username_2,
    t0.email AS email_3,
    t0.password AS password_4,
    ...
FROM
    user t0
WHERE
    t0.id = ?
```

Can I override this query, for add a join and parameters in Where ?

I see this : [Using a Custom Query to Load the User](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user)

**This is not my situation :** *loadUserByUsername()* load with username or email (**u.username = :username OR u.email = :email**), twig make a query with Id (**t0.id = ?**)

Thanks :)

Comment: what do you really need to do ?

Comment: Override default query " app.user " for add join and where :)

Comment: i understand that ... my question was more like, WHY ? what do you want to add in the where ? i mean, do you really need to overide the app.user

Comment: If I call app.user.image (Image = OneToOne), I don't want one more query ... I want to override the native query. This is just an example :)

Comment: don't think you should do it like that. you better create a custom method in your repository and give it to the template

Comment: What is the "app? object/entity?

Comment: Can you post the entity(s) source code?

Comment: `app.user` calls the `getToken()` method on the tokenStorage and the `getUser()` method on the received token. This token is created using the authentication provider (eg. `UserAuthenticationProvider` for `UsernamePasswordToken`) which calls the UserProviders `loadUserByUsername()` method. Long story short: Implement the interface you linked to and you're done.